# R: Adding columns with value found in different dataframe

Tags: r

Sorry if this has been asked before. I am fairly new to R, and strugling a tad with formulating the question correctly.

I have two dataframes imported from a csv, looking similar to this:

```
df1: 
    date time vdd temp seat volume output
    ...  ...  1.8 25   1    ...    ... 
    ...  ...  1.8 -40  0    ...    ... 
    ...  ...  ... ...  ...  ...    ...
```

And

```
df2:
    seat temp vdd noise
    0    -40  1.8 5.3E-09
    1    25   1.8 4.9E-09
    .     .    .   .
```

I want the second dataframe to work as a lookup table, to create a new column in the first dataframe, producing a result like this:

```
df1: 
    date time vdd temp seat volume output noise
    ...  ...  1.8 25   1    ...    ...    4.9E-09
    ...  ...  1.8 -40  0    ...    ...    5.3E-09
    ...  ...  ... ...  ...  ...    ...    ...
```

I have tried looking at merge and match, but I can't wrap my head around how to produce the result I want.

Thanks for any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use `merge()` as you mentioned in your post.

```
merge(df1, df2, by=c("seat", "temp", "vdd"))
```

By default this will keep all records from the first data frame and only corresponding records from the second. To keep all records from both, use `all=T`.

Alternatively you can omit the `by=` argument and it will merge on all common columns.

Comment: Thank you! I tried using merge, but I had several problems - but my problem was generated by not having the same name of the collumns.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could approach this, but I find this to be the easiest:

1. Install this package if you don't already have it:

`install.packages("sqldf")`

It lets you use SQL commands to transform data.

2. Join the data as you see fit:

`require(sqldf)`

`output_table <- sqldf("select df1.*, df2.noise from df1 join df2 on df1.seat = df2.seat")`